# Assigning Connected App to Permission Set through SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I'm working on scripting out a scratch org that will have a Connected App w/ a Permission Set.  I can get the Connected App & Permission Set imported from JSON, and I can assign a user to the permission set.  But I have not found a way to assign the Connected App to the Permission Set through either a) JSON data or b) an SFDX command.

Is the only way to assign the Connected App to the Permission Set through the Salesforce web UI?

Comment: You can assign a Permission Set to a Connected App using `SetupEntityAccess` in Apex code like this: `SetupEntityAccess sea = new SetupEntityAccess( ParentId = permissionSet.Id, SetupEntityId = connectedApp.Id); insert sea;`  I'm not sure how to achieve that directly with JSON data / SFDX though